# Github certificate issue

Tags: ajax, express, github

I am hosting a personal website on github, and I am also building a smart home using a pi and node with express.js for the database. I can acces my pi directly with the ip, I did all the work of port forwarding etc, it works.

Now I am facing the followong problem : Because github is a secured website, it needs a HTTPS request, so I had to configure my express.js to start a https server with the credentials (i.e. key + certificate). But now, my browser blocks the ajax request because the certificate is invalid (see screenshot linked)

How can I have my certificate validated by all browsers ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have express.js running on your pi and your site is stored on GitHub. When you try to access your site on GitHub (via HTTPS), your browser tries to fetch data from your Express.js server without a valid certificate and your browser killed the connection to an unsecured server.

Comment: That's correct,  I created a certificate on my pi using the shell,  but it's not valid when I try to launch the query

Answer (score 0):

For your Pi server to be accessible via an HTTPS connection, you will need to get a SSL certificate, which in turn require you to get a custom domain.

Once you have a custom domain, you can get a free SSL certificate for your HTTPS connection via [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) or [CloudFlare](https://cloudflare.com).

You can get a custom domain for cheap over at [NameCheap](http://namecheap.com).

Comment: I don't want to add another domain,  I am using the free hosting on gîthub, I created a ssl certificate but it's not "recognized"  and when I try to directly access the pi,  it warn me that the connexion is not secured but I can keep browsing on it,  but when it's integrated in a Ajax query,  then it's just blocked by my browser

Comment: @TomFrench You are not getting the problem here. Your site stored on GitHub uses HTTPS, your browser access the GitHub site in HTTPS mode and in that mode you cannot access data from other insecure connection (your Pi server).

Comment: It works when I first visit my pi with https://itsip, then it says me that the certificate is not known but I click keep going. Then the query on gîthub works because I have the certificate. So my guess would be to propose the user to directly accept my certificate and to add it to its certificates pool

Comment: Yes, your self-issued certificate will trigger warnings when accessed directly and blocked when accessed indirectly via another website. Adding the self-issued certificate to the browser might solve this problem for that browser... not 100% sure.